# How can I programmatically record the times of changes in videos?

Tags: video, video-processing

For example, imagine a video with a blue square and a red square in the top right corner of the video. Inside each square is a letter. I am only interested in the times the blue square's letter changes and one caveat is that the squares will shift around a bit (from left to right) based on other squares that may be present.

Some ideas I've come up with are:

- use ffmpeg to crop videos to only display the row of squares (my thought here is that then, the videos are much smaller to process and thus, much faster)
- process those cropped images with something like https://pyscenedetect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/usage/#detection-methods to do threshold based detection and record time codes of changes

Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this? I am proficient in JavaScript and an intermediate Python dev, but also happy to hear of any other languages that may offer the right features. I prefer open source, but also willing to hear about paid solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile an example (stub) plug-in for some processing software such as VirtualDub etc, you can probably get the RGB frames. They can be quickly processed in plain C or C++.

Current content of the blue square can be described as

```
struct {
  char Area[MaxY][MaxX][3];  //This is the actual square contents
  int CurWidth;  //Current width of the square (may vary if it reflects the character width)
} MyArea;
```

The current position can be described as a simple `int CurX;` as far as I understand, significant changes in MyArea should trigger the detector, and changes of CurX should not.

If you're OK with building a tiny plug-in for that, I'll put an example of code somewhere like Pastebin.

UPD: written it as a brain exercise. [Here the example](https://pastebin.com/QGUGSkBz), also added the CurHeight into the structure.

Comment: Appreciate the theoretical and the example code! It's pretty sound afaict, but I'm hoping to find more of a canned solution than I am with rolling my own. Also, my C skills are not what they should be - lol. Hoping there's a decent library out there that I just can't seem to find that would get me most of the way.